# Pytest not running as expected, module not found or collected 0 items

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, pytest

Here is my directory structure. (I deleted `word_count_test.py` it was worth a try, the content was exactly the same as `test_word_count.py`).

[image: directory structure]

The code for unit testing in `word_count.py`

```
from validators import url

def isValidUrl(uri):
    return url(uri)
```

`test_word_count.py` contains

```
import pytest
from src.word_count import isValidUrl

def isValidUrl_test():
    assertTrue(isValidUrl("http://www.bbc.co.uk/news"))

assert 1 == 1
```

Depending on whether I run pytest from the terminal or from within the IDE I get

```
__________________ ERROR collecting test/test_word_count.py ____________________________
ImportError while importing test module '/Users/path/to/the/project/word_counter_service/test/test_word_count.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
test/test_word_count.py:2: in <module>
    from src.word_count import isValidUrl
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 1 error during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
============================================================================================= 1 error in 0.10s =============================================================================================
```

or

```
word_counter_service) mc-n357353:word_counter_service leives01$ pytest
=========================================================== test session starts ===========================================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.8.0, pytest-5.3.2, py-1.8.1, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: /Users/path/to/the/project/word_counter_service
collected 0 items                                                                                                                         

========================================================== no tests ran in 0.10s ==========================================================
```

Comment: Adding `__init__.py` to src and test now makes pytest run in the terminal (however, I don't think this is good practise with pytest). I get the same problem with collected 0 items.

Answer (score 0):

I worked out that I needed to add `__init__.py` to each directory for it to run as expected in either terminal (though I'm not sure that this is best practice).

To make `test_word_count.py` work I changed the code to

```
import pytest
from src.word_count import isValidUrl

def test_isValidUrl():
    assert isValidUrl("http://www.bbc.co.uk/news") == True
```

because assertTrue is not available in Pytest and the test methods also need to begin with `test_`.

I hope this helps someone else.

Comment: `== True` is redundant in the `assert` statement.